# Hex to BGR Hex conversion for KML color in Java

Tags: java, colors, hex, kml, rgb

I'm building a utility that takes placemarks on a web based map and exports them to KML for use in Google Earth. The problem is the hex values I'm given are standard RGB, whereas KML needs BGR (AABBGGRR where AA is the alpha, but that's not relevant here). For simple colors like red (FF0000), the conversion is simple: 0000FF. However, I've found for something like 7DCCFF (which is like a light blue), simply reversing the string doesn't yield the same color in Google Earth. Am I missing something blatantly obvious here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

Splitting with regex `(?<=\G..)`

```
 String color = "123456";
 String[] list = color.split("(?<=\\G..)");
 for(String s : list) {
     System.out.println(s);
 }
```

Which will give you output of:

```
12
34
56
```

Now you simply do some swap among `list[0], list[1] and list[2]`

The regex `(?<=\G..)` matches an empty string that has the **last match** (`\G`) followed by **two characters** (`..`) **before** it (`(?<= )`)

Comment: Yep, your answer made me realize what I was doing wrong and furthermore why it worked with colors like yellow. Reversing the string swaps the values for the individual colors. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I've developped a simple PHP tool to convert the KML / RGB colors, using these two PHP functions :

```
function rgbToKml($color, $aa="ff"){
$rr = substr($color, 0, 2);
$gg = substr($color, 2, 2);
$bb = substr($color, 4, 2);
return $aa.$bb.$gg.$rr;
}
function kmlToRgb($color){
$rr = substr($color, 6, 2);
$gg = substr($color, 4, 2);
$bb = substr($color, 2, 2);
return $rr.$gg.$bb;
}
```

Check the example here : http://netdelight.be/kml/